# Customized Alert View Using Three20

Tags: iphone, ios4, three20, uialertview

I want to create a customized `UIAlertView` and since I'm already using [Three20](http://three20.info) I thought I'd give it a shot.

I saw they have `TTAlertViewController` class.

I tried to call it like this:

```
TTAlertViewController* vc = [[TTAlertViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyAlertView" bundle:nil];
[vc addButtonWithTitle:@"OK" URL:@"MyApp://buttonOk"];
```

But it doesn't seem to work (just showing that button) , I guess cause they are already implementing `LoadView` , which to my understanding "kills" any way to use a Nib file.

Does anyone know how to customize alert view using Three20's UI objects ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This may not be your exact problem, and there may be multiple issues , but it is one possible solution to what you describe, and may help others who arrive here and do have this exact issue.

In order for a class to correctly "hydrate" from a NIB in "initWithNibName", you'll need to specify that class as the owner in the NIB.  Here's how to do this in XCode 4.x (where IB is now embedded in Xcode)

1. Select the "File's Owner" in the left object "outline view" (under "Placeholders" if you've got the dock expanded so words appear).
2. Select the "Identity Inspector" from the right side "Utilities" pane. (3rd from the left in my case)
3. In the "Custom Class" section, enter the exact class name (TTAlertViewController) in the field marked "Class".

There's also this, from Apple's documentation of the "loadView" method, but it doesn't specify the behavior if this counsel is ignored:

> If you use Interface Builder to create your views and initialize the
>   view controller—that is, you initialize the view using the
>   initWithNibName:bundle: method, set the nibName and nibBundle
>   properties directly, or create both your views and view controller in
>   Interface Builder—then you must not override this method.